# How to access two different services from the same ble device

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-8.1

For example, I have two heart rate monitors paired with my tablet PC.
I'm using such code to get list of HRM devices:

```
var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync
(
    GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.HeartRate)
);
```

Then I show a listbox in GUI with device names got from devices[i].Name.
For example, I select device with index 0. Then I can get access to it HR serivice and HRM characteristic:

```
var service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);
var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristics(attCharacteristicUuids.HeartRateMeasurement);
```

Along with heart rate I need a battery status. How can I get access to battery service of the same (already selected) device?

Answer (score 0):

Some information before we start:

You do **have to pair** your Bluetooth devices **with your computer**, before you could scan them!

[Listing your paired devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120882/list-and-connect-to-bluetooth-devices):

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear();

var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

foreach (var device in devices)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(device);
}
```

If you want to know the battery life of the Bluetooth device:

[How to get the battery level after connect to the BLE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device)

To access multiple services at once, you need to *"reconnect"* to the device:

> Device A can connect only one at a time to service S on Device B. Device A can connect to service S on Device B, C, D and E, etc at the same time.

[@alanjmcf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35049/alanjmcf)

Source: [Establishing multiple bluetooth SPPs at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282200/establishing-multiple-bluetooth-spps-at-the-same-time)

But do not get confused with the method [`GetAllIncludedServices();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice.getallincludedservices.aspx), because it does really return "*included services*". As one answer stated at [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598977/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-to-get-all-the-services-for-a-bluetooth-le-ble-device):

> You probably don't want to get the "included services". Included services is a special concept in BLE which I doubt you are using that is used to link one service from another.

[@Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556495/emil)

Comment: Devices are paired and there are no problems with device listing. There also no problems with getting bettery life without getting HRM. I have problem with accessing BOTH servicies of ONCE selected device.